# React setup startup page

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS.

I'm using command "npx create-react-app reactproject" to create a website by using react.But i dont know how to configure page (html or js) as default page when project run? I have googling on this, but not able to get answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A react app initialized with `create-react-app` starts on the page rendered by `./src/App.js`.

In the `render()` function of that file you can create your page and include navigation for other pages.

```
class App extends Component {

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>My home page</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can i configure to my own js?

Comment: The `App.js` file contains the code that defines the `App` component. This component is a container for the rest of the components in your app. Think of it like a `main()` function or an `index.html` page, it's just where the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the HTML page the react app renders on you can add the ID "root" to  a div and your react app will render within that however i don't recommend it.

Obviously remove root from index.html

I recommend you read React docs https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

if you meant you want to render a different React component on the home page you can use React Router like so:

```
<Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home} />
```

also install React Router via npm and include it:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```